# Remove part of a string in R

Tags: r, string, date

I'm new to R and I have tried the search function but couldn't make much sense of what I found.

I have a string like this: `20/08/2016`

How can I convert it to `20/08/16`

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: See `help("gsub")`

Comment: Keep dates as dates, convert to date, then format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try something like below

```
s <- "20/08/2016"
format(as.Date(s,"%d/%m/%Y"),"%d/%m/%y")
# [1] "20/08/16"
```

or

```
gsub("(.*/)\\d{2}(.*)","\\1\\2",s)
# [1] "20/08/16"
```